# JCombo + override toString

Tags: java, jcombobox, tostring

Alright, I am working on a rather large program.

I will try to put in only what you need.

So right now, the **`comboBox`** is filling (with the override `toString`), and the first item is selected.

When I choose different parameters and force the contents of the `comboBox` to change, the new list is put into the `comboBox` and the first item is selected again.

I can see the update, so I know it is filling properly.

**The problem is** that when I select anything in the `comboBox`, nothing happens.

The first item remains selected, none of my `System.out.println` lines are printing, so nothing is being executed.

When I remove my override `toString`, everything works as intended.

The strange part, past that, is when having this override `toString` removed, it falls back on the parent class who **has** an override `toString`.

**What is going on?**

To my understanding the `toString` literally changes what is displayed, it does not change the data.

I am adding the objects to the `comboBox`, but displaying a bit of the information.

```
public class Belt extends Part{
    //variable initialization and methods
    @override
    public String toString(){
    String display = this.getCode() + " - " + this.color;
    return display;
}

public final class Something implements ActionListener{
    //variable initialization and methods
    //there are several methods that call the fillBeltCombo()

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    private void pad(GridBagConstraints c){
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.insets.left = 10;
        c.insets.right = 10;
        c.insets.top = 5;
        c.insets.bottom = 5;
    }

    beltCombo = new JComboBox();
    beltCombo.setVisible(true);
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    c.gridx = 4;
    c.gridy = 9;
    beltCombo.addActionListener((ActionEvent eventBelt) -> {
        JComboBox beltCodeCombo1 = (JComboBox) eventBelt.getSource();
        if(beltCombo.getItemCount()>0){
            currentProduct.setBelt((Belt)beltCodeCombo1.getSelectedItem());
        }else{/*do nothing*/}
    });
    pane.add(beltCombo, c);

    public static void fillBeltCombo(ArrayList<Belt> list){
        beltCombo.removeAllItems();
        int size = list.size();
        for(int x=0; x<size; x++){
            beltCombo.addItem(list.get(x));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is 'c' above? As in `c.gridwidth = 2;`.  Also, you're making a new combo box each time the action listener is invoked.  That might be the reason you don't see updates to an existing combo box.  Was the new combo box intentional?

Comment: @ markspace Added my GridBagConstraints to the code to show what 'c' is. As for making a new comboBox each time the listener is invoked, I do not remember reasoning for it. I picked that up somewhere on these forums when implementing the ActionListener. So yes it was intentional (and it works on my comboBoxes that do not have another toString override), but I cannot defend why I use it. Just became habit.

Comment: So ok, now the question is when you say "when I select anything in the comboBox, nothing happens" which combo box are you referring to?  You will have one combox box for each click.

Comment: The second comboBox is temporary. The "beltCodeCombo1" is invisible and is never put anywhere. If memory serves me, that section of code is to add the action listener and event code without creating a whole separate function elsewhere in the program. When I say "select anything from the combo" I am referring to the only one that can ever be seen and interacted with, beltCombo.
Regardless of the extra combo box. When the toString is removed, this program works as intended.

Comment: I really think you need to produce an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Your edit changed things around.  You say you can't get your `println` to work with the `toString` method but there's no println in the code above, so how is anyone to guess what is going on?  MCVE please.

Comment: @markspace I am not sure I can produce one, this program is ~7k lines of code through 20 classes. Belt is a PartByArray, which is a Part. I am creating the Belt array from an excel file. I removed the println from the example code to thin it out, it is not functional, but troubleshooting in nature. All my edit did was explain that I am using gridbaglayout manager, not relevant to the problem at hand. Thank you for the link for MCVE, I will attempt to create one tomorrow that is...condensed but functional.

Comment: No worries, and good luck.  It's just that I can see too many possibilities what **might** be wrong to guess at any one of them.  We'll needs something that reproduces the problem to be able to pin it down.;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aright, so based on yesterdays successful creation (which I was frustrated by) I continued to fill in the skeleton until it broke again. 
 - Adjusted classes to reflect the actual types of data that I was dealing with.
 - Added my override equals method <-------problem

What happened was that when I originally created the equals override, all of the toStrings were the same, and that was displayed in the comboBox.
So the equals override looked like

```
@Override public boolean equals(Object other){
    if (other == null) return false;
    return (String.valueOf(other)).equals(this.description);
}
```

The problem with this, was that when I was asked to change what was displayed in the comboBox, I did not realize that the comboBox seems to use that equals check. The new other Object was

```
this.getCode() + " - " + this.color;
```

and it was being compared to num, which returned false.

Now correct me if I am wrong, but the moral of the story seems to be: **JComboBox will not let you select something from the list that does not equal something on the list.** So because my equals override changed how the objects were compared:
 string value of object, compared to string variable of the object-
the same object was not equaling itself.
The adjusted code:

```
@Override public boolean equals(Object other){
    if (other == null) return false;
    return ((Parent)other).description.equals(this.description);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So taking the advice of markspace, I created a MCVE (the best I could while maintaining what my program was doing). Everything down there is done in my real program, although more complicated. I am not sure yet what my program is doing wrong, however I did find out that **what I am trying to do is possible**, I am able to select an item from the second comboBox while using an Override toString in the subclass. Now I just have to track the problem down in the actual code...

```
package minitest;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainClass {
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel pane;
    JLabel label1, label2;
    JComboBox comboA, comboB;
    ArrayList<Parent> parents = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Grandchild> grandkids = new ArrayList<>();
    Parent parent1 = new Parent(1);
    Parent parent2 = new Parent(2);
    Grandchild grandkid1 = new Grandchild(1,1,"oneone");
    Grandchild grandkid2 = new Grandchild(1,2,"onetwo");
    Grandchild grandkid3 = new Grandchild(2,1,"twoone");
    Grandchild grandkid4 = new Grandchild(2,2,"twotwo");
    public class Parent{
        protected int num;
        public Parent(int num){
            this.num = num;
        }
        @Override public String toString(){
            return String.valueOf(num);
        }
    }
    public class Child extends Parent{
        private double dbl;
        public Child(int num, double dbl){
            super(num);
            this.dbl = dbl;
        }
    }
    public class Grandchild extends Child{
        private String str;
        public Grandchild(int num, double dbl, String str){
            super(num, dbl);
            this.str = str;
        }
        @Override public String toString(){
            return this.num + " - " + this.str;
        }
    }
    //Fill passed combo with each item from passed ArrayList
    public void fillCombo(ArrayList list, JComboBox target){
        target.removeAllItems();
        int size = list.size();
        for(int x = 0; x < size; x++){
            target.addItem(list.get(x));
        }
    }
    //remove all items from combobox except selected item
    public void comboUpdate(JComboBox combo){
        if(combo.getSelectedItem()==null){
            /*donothing*/
        }else{
            int size = (combo.getItemCount()-1);
            System.out.println("size: "+size);
            for (int x=size; x>=0; x--) {
                if(combo.getSelectedItem().equals(combo.getItemAt(x))){
                    /*donothing*/
                    System.out.println(combo.getSelectedItem()+" is selected");
               }else{
                    System.out.println(combo.getItemAt(x)+" is now removed");
                    combo.removeItemAt(x);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Add each item from passed ArrayList if not equal to the selected item
    public void removeDuplicate(JComboBox combo, ArrayList array){
        System.out.println("removeDuplicate: "+array);
        if(combo.getSelectedItem()==null){
            System.out.println("combo.getSelectedItem==null");
            fillCombo(array, combo);
        }else{
            boolean validChoice = false;
            int arraySize = array.size();
                for(int x = 0; x < arraySize; x++){
                    if(combo.getSelectedItem().equals(array.get(x))){
                        System.out.println(combo.getSelectedItem()+" == "+array.get(x));
                        validChoice = true;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println(combo.getSelectedItem()+" != "+array.get(x));
                        combo.addItem(array.get(x));
                    }
                }
            if(validChoice == false){
                System.out.println("removeItemAt(0)");
                combo.removeItemAt(0);
            }
        }
    }
//fill comboB with grandchild objects whos int match the selected partent objects int
    public void fillComboB(){
        System.out.println("grandkids: "+grandkids);
        ArrayList<Grandchild> temp = copyArrayList(grandkids);
        System.out.println("temp: "+temp);
        comboUpdate(comboB);
        int size = (temp.size()-1);
        for(int x=size; x>=0; x--){
            if(temp.get(x).num==((Parent)comboA.getSelectedItem()).num){
                /*donothing*/
                System.out.println("donothing: temp.get("+x+")="+temp.get(x));
            }else{
                System.out.println("temp.remove("+x+")="+temp.get(x));
                temp.remove(x);
            }
        }
        removeDuplicate(comboB, temp);
    }
    public ArrayList copyArrayList(ArrayList list){
        ArrayList<Object> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        int size = list.size();
        for(int x=0; x<size; x++){
            temp.add(list.get(x));
        }
        return temp;
    }
    public MainClass(){
        parents.add(parent1);
        parents.add(parent2);
        grandkids.add(grandkid1);
        grandkids.add(grandkid2);
        grandkids.add(grandkid3);
        grandkids.add(grandkid4);
        frame = new JFrame("frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        comboA = new JComboBox();
        fillCombo(parents, comboA);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        comboA.addActionListener((ActionEvent eventComboA) -> {
            System.out.println("eventComboA");
            JComboBox comboA1 = (JComboBox) eventComboA.getSource();
            if(comboA.getItemCount()>0){
                System.out.println("comboA.getItemCount>0: "+(Parent)comboA1.getSelectedItem());
                fillComboB();
            }
        });
        pane.add(comboA, c);

        comboB = new JComboBox();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        comboB.addActionListener((ActionEvent eventComboB) -> {
            System.out.println("eventComboB");
            JComboBox comboB1 = (JComboBox) eventComboB.getSource();
            if(comboB.getItemCount()>0){
                System.out.println("comboB.getItemCount>0: "+(Grandchild)comboB1.getSelectedItem());
            }
        });
        pane.add(comboB, c);

        frame.setContentPane(pane);
        frame.setSize(150,150);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private static void runGUI(){
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(false);
        MainClass create = new MainClass();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            runGUI();
        });
    }
}
```